# Java RSS Notification Manager

Tags: java, rss

Does anyone know of a java library or JSP Web Application that can do the following...

1. Subscribe to an RSS feeds
2. Manage User Email Subscriptions to certain events in the feed. (add/remove)
3. Notify the users as the feed come in through the feed

Example:
User A wants to be notified on all news related to "technology" from the Google News RSS feed to someone1@someone.com
User B wants to be notified on all news related to "education" from the Google News RSS feed to someone2@someone.com
User A wants to be notified on all news related to "technology->Apple" from the Google News RSS feed to someone1@someone.com And someone2@someone.com

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check Rome and Informa libraries.

Answer (score 0):

RSS utilities by Rodrigo Oliveira will make it dead easy to parse rss feeds, it wont handle subscriptions etc, you'd have to do that.
http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javaserverpages/rss_utilities/

Comment: Thanks for that library.

I found a good set of utilities like ROME to parse RSS feeds but i have to imagine there is some application out there to handle subscriptions...